# junit testing with mock objects: stub inner function calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

So I was trying to test `ping()` method and make sure that it calls `connect()` and `disconnect()`. I mocked the object `foo` and an object `Connection`. Then I did `stub(mockFoo.connect()).toReturn(mockConn)` hoping that then `ping()` should return true for me to assert. However, somehow this stubbing is not going through. I'm suspecting that maybe when connect is called internally, mockFoo didn't actually invoke `connect()`, hence didn't return the mock Connection, but I'm not sure.

```
public class foo{
    public boolean ping(){
        bool ping = false; 
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
           conn = connect();
           ping = true;
        }catch(Exception e){
        }finally{
           disconnect(conn);
        }
        return ping;
    }

    public Connection connect(){
        //some implementation
        return connect
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you don't mock the unit under test itself. Mockito will use default stubbing behavior for all methods. So a call to `ping()` will simply return the default `false`, and no other methods of `foo` will be called.

You could do partial mocking by making a spy on foo and then stub the connect method as you have. Though I would not recommend this.
Ideally you would have your dependencies on collaborators (in this case the Connection) injected. Setting up a connection, and using a connection are different responsibilities and really belong on different classes.

So more like this :

```
public class Foo {

    private final ConnectionProvider connectionProvider;

    private Foo(ConnectionProvider connectionProvider) {
        this.connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
    }

    public boolean ping(){
            boolean ping = false;
            Connection connection = null;
            try{
                connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
                ping = true;
            }catch(Exception e){
                // TODO handle this exception
            }finally{
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO handle this exception
                }
            }
            return ping;
        }

}

public interface ConnectionProvider {

    Connection getConnection();
}

@org.junit.Test
public void testConnection() throws Exception {
    ConnectionProvider mockProvider = mock(ConnectionProvider.class);
    Connection mockConnection = mock(Connection.class);
    when(mockProvider.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);

    Foo foo = new Foo(mockProvider);

    assertTrue(foo.ping());

    verify(mockConnection).close();
}
```